# 403 Response for Google Login on Android

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus, google-plus-signin

When I do a Google+ Login I get the following error on my signed APK:

```
Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

Generated a SHA1 fingerprint for my signed APK using my keystore, alias and keystore password and added it to the Google Plus developer console but I still get the error.

What am I doing wrong?

My debug version is working properly.

I get the following errors in my logcat

```
10-02 09:31:28.460   7089-13931/? E/MDM﹕ [230] b.run: Couldn't connect to Google API client: ConnectionResult{statusCode=API_UNAVAILABLE, resolution=null, message=null}
10-02 09:31:31.964  22172-22356/? E/Volley﹕ [2260] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 403 for https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me
```

Also when I try to do a request to load friends using `Plus.PeopleApi.loadConnected(...` I get the following error:

```
Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}
```

I think it has something to do with my SHA1 then, but I don't think I did anything wrong while generating it.

Comment: have you used oauth 2.0 ?

Comment: Yes I used the OAuth 2.0 Client ID. Both for my dev and live version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error 403 means Forbidden/or no permission to access the page/site with the given login credentials.

**Moreover you get different SHA-1 for signed and debug version of your apk,** please keep that in mind.

Below info I took from. https://developers.google.com/+/sign-in-faq

The reasons you get 403 error

```
403 - Forbidden

Refer to the API's quota in the Google Developer Console to ensure your application is not exceeding the request quota.

Ensure Google+ API is enabled in the Developer Console for the application you are testing.

Confirm the requested scopes correspond to what is required to invoke the API.

Verify that this is not a rare case of requesting a user's circle data while the user is a Google App user who has disabled Google+.
```

Dont forget to use the Oauth 2.0 from your dev console

Comment: I generated a SHA-1 for my signed and debug version of my apk. They are indeed both different and I added them both to the Google Developer Console but I still get the error.

Comment: try to remove the debug versions sha1, n just have signed versions sha

Comment: 1. I checked the quota's. `Remaining 20,000,000 requests/day 100% of total`
2. Google+ API is enabled
3. The request scopes are working in the dev apk.
4. I am not requesting circle data. The sign in is working on the dev version on the same device as where the live version isn't working

Comment: I deleted the dev SHA-1 but it is still not working.

Comment: I did. I published as Alpha and published to me as a tester. Downloaded it from the Play store. Payments are working, Google+ sign in isn't working.

Comment: I will keep trying to find a solution, until then if you get solution by yourself please kindly post as an answer

Comment: I am also trying to. Still haven't found an solution. I will post it when I found one. Could it be possible the SHA-1 I generated isn't correct?

Comment: The way I generated it: `keytool -exportcert -alias appkeystore -keystore keystore.jks -list -v` This is the same key, alias and password that I use to create the signed APK.

Comment: if you used the same procedure of getting sha1 as you did for  debug, then its fine, but your sha-1 will be different for debug and signed(i know you knew this :-) )

Comment: Yeah I used the same way. But it's strange that my dev version is working and my signed apk isnt.

Comment: When I log the onConnectionFailed result it says: `SIGN_IN_REQUIRED`  https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/ConnectionResult.html#SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

Comment: Maybe try it in another device with all the gmail accounts u have

Comment: I tried it with multiple devices and multiple gmail accounts. With an account that wasn't registered with the app yet got the screen to accept the permissions but after that it still got the 403 error.

Comment: Google+ Login error isn't fixed yet but I also get the following error: `Status{statusCode=NETWORK_ERROR, resolution=null}` even when I'm debugging..

Comment: what do you get in physical device ?

Comment: What do you mean? I am running the app on my physical devices when I get the error.

Comment: @BartBergmans did you get an api key from google dev console for g+ sign- in?

Comment: I am using OAuth 2.0 client IDs instead of API keys

Comment: When I am using my developer account I can login but with my personal account I can't..

Comment: Could it be possible that I got an error because I was using an account that wasn't linked to the app as an developer?

Comment: your comment is valid, i thought the same, but it shoule technically not happen

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91627/discussion-between-penta-and-bart-bergmans).